# How to output results in CSV format instead of markdown from Palm API?

Tags: palm-api

I'm new to using the PalmML API and I"m trying to generate results that return in CSV format. No matter what I try, I am getting markdown format. Here is example prompt.

```
              const result = await client.generateText({
                model:MODEL_NAME,
                prompt: {
                    text: 'Generate a list of top 10 websites and return results in comma separated value format, not markdown format. Put field names in first row.',
                    format: 'csv',
                    delimiter: ',',
                    quote: '"', 
                  },
                 
               });
```

The output is always in markdown format like following:

```
| Rank | Website | Alexa Global Rank |
|---|---|---|
| 1 | Google | 1 |
| 2 | YouTube | 2 |
| 3 | Facebook | 3 |
| 4 | Baidu | 4 |
| 5 | Wikipedia | 5 |
| 6 | Amazon | 6 |
| 7 | Tencent | 7 |
| 8 | Twitter | 8 |
| 9 | Instagram | 9 |
| 10 | Reddit | 10 |
```

Is there a way to have it output CSV format? Or Do I need to convert markdown to CSV on my own?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can remove these fields as they aren't going anywhere (see the [API docs](https://developers.generativeai.google/api/rest/generativelanguage/models/generateText#textprompt)):

```
prompt: {
  format: 'csv',
  delimiter: ',',
  quote: '"',
},
```

There are a few approaches that will probably help. As LLMs are just auto-complete services, you can try giving it the start of the CSV example in a zero shot request (I would also remove `not markdown format` to avoid including references to `markdown format`), e.g.

**Zero-shot prompt**:

```
Generate a list of top 10 websites and return results in comma separated value format.

websites.csv:
rank,website,url
```

You can often do better with a few-shot prompt by giving examples.

**Few-shot prompt** (1-shot really):

```
Task: Top-5 ice cream flavours in CSV format.
icecream.csv:
rank,flavour,colour
1,chocolate,brown
2,vanilla,white
3,strawberry,pink
4,banana,yellow
5,mint choc-chip,green

Task: Top-10 websites in CSV format
websites.csv:
rank,name,url
```

---

Another approach is to get the model to come up with results in stages.

**Prompt 1**:

```
The top 10 websites by traffic are
```

**Response**:

```
The top 10 websites by traffic are:
1. Google
2. YouTube
...
```

**Prompt 2**:

```
The top 10 websites by traffic are:
1. Google
2. YouTube
...

The above list in comma-separated format is:
rank,website
```

You can even do this dynamically.

**Prompt**:

```
The top websites, in CSV format are:
```

Try to evaluate the results, if it can't be coerced into CSV then append the prompt with a correction stanza.

```
The top websites, in CSV format are:
| Rank | Website |
|---|---|
| 1 | Google |
...

That was not CSV, in comma-separated format, it is:
```

This last approach is a bit better suited to the [`generateMessage`](https://developers.generativeai.google/api/rest/generativelanguage/models/generateMessage) API but you can make it work in text too.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just creating a simple conversation tool that converts markdown to CSV...as the api seems to like to output markdown format...and it works very well.